# How do I keep track of model changes that aren't synced to the server?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-binding, backbone-events

I have a form, that updates my model with change events executing a lot of `set` methods.

```
model.set({Name: newname });
```

The same could be achieved automatically with Derick Bailey's wonderful [modelbinding plugin](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.modelbinding).

Anyway, the model is updated constantly when changing the form. BUT, unless I click the save button which actually executes a `model.save();` call, none of these changes will ever make it into the database.

Thus, if I now navigate away from the form via:

- back button from the browser
- other buttons in navigation opening another view

it is immediately clear, the model was saved with it's new name, yet it was never saved to the database, (refreshing with <kbd>F5</kbd> shows that)

I'm looking for a useful solution to this problem;
so far I've been thinking of:

- adding a `model.save()` on any blur event of a form element (would still cause many save calls to the server for just 1 model ***not ideal**
- trying to hack in a save on the exit of the form ***not ideal**
- trying to restore the model to it's original state (model reset or similar)

***not ideal** : user does navigate away from the form, indicating his wish NOT to save it's data, and here i am trying to hack in a save anyway.

How would I achieve this resetting the model to it's state it was in before changing the form?

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you could save the model's initial state. But the real solution that you're looking for is to call [`set`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-set) instead of `save`. It will perform your validation without syncing to your persistence layer (i.e., the database). It will also trigger the `change` event so your view can react accordingly. Then, when you're ready to save, you can.

Comment: i rephrased my question as it seems you misunderstood me, i want to reset a model, when a user decides not to save it, after the model was updated with the model.set() numerous times during the user interacting with the form.

Comment: That doesn't really make too much sense. Not saving it anywhere will cause it to be "reset" effectively, since the next time the page is visited it will have whatever properties it originally did.

Comment: sure it does make sense, you are not necessarily moving away to another 'Page', it could be a web application, and as long as you stay withing the application (no page refresh) you keep using the same set of models / collections. untill they are updated or reset by the script. so that is what i'm trying to find, where to reset the model.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. I'm confused by what your question says versus what your comment says. You want to (a) *save* the model (to the database) while the form is being edited, and (b) *reset* the model (in the database) to what it was before the user began editing the form?

Comment: nope, that is where you are mistaken, i am saving form changes into the model (trough a modelbinding plugin, so when you type in a new 'name' for example, the model's name property is updated constantly to reflect the form changes (model.set({'name': 'newname'});). however the save to the backend/server/database only happens on model.save(); ... if for some reason model.save(); is NOT executed, when a user navigates away within the application, the model has updated values that arn't in the database.  hope you understand it now :)